# Passing Datatable Rows to backing bean

Tags: jsf-2, datatable

I want to pass all the editable-datatable items to the backing bean. The problem is the changes I made to datatable are not passed to the backing bean.

How do I pass the changes I made to the list of datatable items from a JSF page to the backing bean?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide us your datatable jsf page code and corresponding ManagedBean code. I think may be there are any silly mistake on your managedBean side.